# Voltage regulation in alternator

Tags: power, generator, alternator

> A single phase, 2000 V alternator has armature resistance and
>   reactance of 0.8 Ω and 4 Ω respectively. The voltage regulation of
>   alternator at 100 A load at 0.8 leading power factor is _______?

**My approach**

$$V_{nl} = 2000 \text{ V}$$
When loaded
$$V_{l} = 2000 - 100 \angle \cos^{-1}0.8 (0.8 +j4) = 2206.9 \text{ V}$$
In alternator \$V_{reg}\$ is defined as
$$ V_{reg} =  \frac{|V_{nl}| - |V_l|}{|V_l|} * 100 = -9.38 \%$$
Am I right ? Because when I saw the answer it was given -6.96%.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sign error in your calculation.
For unloaded operation, you have : V = E. So:
$$E_{nl} = 2000V$$

You want to calculate the variation of E you need to have in order to ensure that V stay constant when the alternator is loaded :

$$ E_l = V + R \times I + j \times X \times I $$
$$ E_l = 2000 + (0.8 + j \times 4) \times I = 1824 +  368j $$
$$ \left | E_l \right | = 1861 V $$

Note that E<sub>l</sub> is **lower** than E<sub>nl</sub> because of the leading power factor.
Finally :
$$ {{1861 - 2000} \over {2000}} = -6.96\% $$

Comment: Haven't you change the formula used for calculating the voltage regulation. It's alternator so the reference taken should be \$E_l\$ ?

Comment: Basically, I used the formula which is given here : http://www.electricalengineeringinfo.com/2014/11/voltage-regulation-of-synchronous-generator-alternator-using-synchronous-impedance-method.html . It corresponds to the difference (EMF(loaded)-EMF(unloaded)/EMF(unloaded) = (EMF(loaded)-V)/V. This gives the amount of change you need to apply to the EMF in order to get a constant output voltage (V).

Comment: The formula in the link simply relates terminal and internal voltage of an alternator. Check http://nptel.ac.in/courses/108106071/pdfs/1_9.pdf

Comment: The discrepancy is due to defining 2000V as the terminal voltage at the specified load versus at no load.   The problem statement is a bit ambiguous in this regard.